# Group objects with keys based on its index to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Does anyone know how to group object of arrays to a new array of object arrays based on its index with Javascript? I'm quite new to this so I'm quite stuck here

For example I have this object :

```
{
  'first': [
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I love you'
    },
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I miss you!'
    },
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I hate you!'
    }
  ],
  'second': [
    {
      name: 'jeremy',
      text: 'Wow'
    }
  ],
  'third': [
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'You ugly'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'You handsome'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'you beautiful'
    }
  ],
 'fourth': [
    {
      name: 'tom',
      text: 'this is cool!'
    },
    {
      name: 'tom',
      text: 'this is hard'
    }
  ]
}
```

which I want to transform to something like :

```
[
  [
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I love you'
    },
    {
      name: 'jeremy',
      text: 'Wow'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'You ugly'
    },
    {
      name: 'tom',
      text: 'this is cool!'
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I miss you!'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'You handsome'
    },
    {
      name: 'tom',
      text: 'this is hard'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: 'jimmy',
      text: 'I hate you!'
    },
    {
      name: 'john',
      text: 'you beautiful'
    }
  ]
]
```

so 'first'[1],'second'[1], 'third'[1], 'fourth'[1] should group to the first array as array of objects and 'first'[2],'second'[2], 'third'[2], 'fourth'[2] should go to the second array as array of objects and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mushroomator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487348/mushroomator)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72129755/14956277) is probably the most concise way to do this.

If you're newer to JavaScript, functional programming, or programming altogether, I think the following is a decent intro-level approach that might be easier to understand.

The underlying logic is the same, the steps have just been made more explicit/more apparent.

1. Create an `output` array that will hold the result.
2. Get the `first`, `second`, `third`, and `fourth` arrays from `data` by using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).
3. For each of the arrays from step 2, iterate over their items using a `for` loop.
4. If `output` doesn't already have a nested array for the current index, create one.
5. [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the item in the current array at the current index into the array at the current index in the `output`.

```js
const data = {
  first:[{name:"jimmy",text:"I love you"},{name:"jimmy",text:"I miss you!"},{name:"jimmy",text:"I hate you!"}],
  second:[{name:"jeremy",text:"Wow"}],
  third:[{name:"john",text:"You ugly"},{name:"john",text:"You handsome"},{name:"john",text:"you beautiful"}],
  fourth:[{name:"tom",text:"this is cool!"},{name:"tom",text:"this is hard"}]
};

const output = [];
for (let arr of Object.values(data)) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (output[i] === undefined) {
      output[i] = [];
    }
    output[i].push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript and this is really easy to understand for me.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to do this.

```js
const input = {
  first: [
    {
      name: "jimmy",
      text: "I love you",
    },
    {
      name: "jimmy",
      text: "I miss you!",
    },
    {
      name: "jimmy",
      text: "I hate you!",
    },
  ],
  second: [
    {
      name: "jeremy",
      text: "Wow",
    },
  ],
  third: [
    {
      name: "john",
      text: "You ugly",
    },
    {
      name: "john",
      text: "You handsome",
    },
    {
      name: "john",
      text: "you beautiful",
    },
  ],
  fourth: [
    {
      name: "tom",
      text: "this is cool!",
    },
    {
      name: "tom",
      text: "this is hard",
    },
  ],
};

const output = Object.values(input).reduce(
  (all, cur) => (
    cur.forEach((item, idx) =>
      idx < all.length ? all[idx].push(item) : (all[idx] = [item])
    ),
    all
  ),
  []
);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

First of all, we don't care about the keys of the `input` Object, therefore we can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to just obtain the values.

Then, the idea is to start with an empty array `all` (second argument of `reduce()`) and then loop over the `input`.

Then for each element `cur` we loop over all the `items` of this element and for each of these `items` we check whether we have this element's index (`idx`) in the `all` array already.

If we don't, this index is larger then any of the previously added indices and we need to extend our `all` array in order to hold that values. As we expect multiple values for a given spot, we need to use an array as an value for that spot. If we already have at least one value for a given index, we already have an array at the given index and we just need to `push()` the new item onto the `all` array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach where you shift from each subarray the next item so to collect the next subarray for the result:

```js
let obj = {'first': [{name: 'jimmy',text: 'I love you'},{name: 'jimmy',text: 'I miss you!'},{name: 'jimmy',text: 'I hate you!'}],'second': [{name: 'jeremy',text: 'Wow'}],'third': [{name: 'john',text: 'You ugly'},{name: 'john',text: 'You handsome'},{name: 'john',text: 'you beautiful'}],'fourth': [{name: 'tom',text: 'this is cool!'},{name: 'tom',text: 'this is hard'}]};

let arr = Object.values(obj),
    result = [];
while ((arr = arr.filter(sub => sub.length)).length) {
    result.push(arr.map(sub => sub.shift()));
}
console.log(result);
```